# Search through a JavaScript object and its nested properties looking for something in underscore

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, where-clause

I am looking to use [*.where*](http://underscorejs.org/#where) or [.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) to look through an array of objects that look like:

[image]

Looking for anything that the user inputs that might match.

So imaging, you have this expanded object but you have an array of them. Well as you can see here, there is a relationship between this object (user) and profile (the expanded node). If I enter in (into a search box) "CA", I should get all matching elements back because as we see here: `user.profile.data.country === 'CA'` evaluates to true.

Now If I enter in "Kyle", again I should get this object back because the middle_name is Kyle.

The question is, how do I use `where` or `find` to search an array of objects, going as deep as their nesting goes to search for a value that matches?

An example of how deep nesting can go:

```
- user
  - profile
  - contact_info
  - id_verification
  - investments (array)
    - offering
      - company
```

If I type in "shoppers" and shoppers is a company it would then return that object. **Ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to find a property with a given value;
I added a path attribute to indicate where the nested object was found

```
var data = {
    user: {
        profile: {},
        contact_info: {},
        id_verification: {
            name: 'any'
        },
        investments: [{
            offering: "an offer",
            company: "acme"
        }, {
            offering: "an offer",
            company: "shopping"
        }]
    }
}


function search(obj, toMatch, path) {
    path = path ? path : '';
    if ((!_.isObject(obj) && !_.isArray(obj)) || _.isEmpty(obj)) return false;
    var i = _.indexOf(_.values(obj), toMatch)
    if (i > -1) {
        var f = {}
        f[_.keys(obj)[i]] = _.values(obj)[i];
        f.path = path;
        return f;
    } else {
        path = path + '|ANY'
        for (var v in obj) {
            var a = path.split('|')
            a.pop();
            a.push(v);
            path = a.join('|');
            var found = search(obj[v], toMatch, path);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
}
search(data, 'shopping')
```